# Problem with constant Array with fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I created a constant array to use in spinner inside of fragment. When I try to run the code, the app crashes. I've tried to find a solution, but couldn't.
The really weird part, it worked perfectly yesterday when I worked on it, and today it's crashes.

this is my fragment:

```
    class PersonalDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var listener: OnChangeFragmentListener

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        listener = getListenerOrThrowException(OnChangeFragmentListener::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal_deatails, container, false)



        v.spinnerAge.adapter = ArrayAdapter<Int>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, LIST_AGE)



        v.btnGoDetails.setOnClickListener { listener.changeFragment() }



        return v
    }
```

this is my Constant class:

```
    class Constant {

    companion object {

        @JvmField val LIST_AGE = getAgeList()

        private fun getAgeList(): Array<Int?> {
            val array = arrayOfNulls<Int>(83)
            for (i in array.indices){

                    var age = i + 17
                    array[i] = age

            }

            return  array

        }
    }
```

Error Log:

```
    2019-06-06 19:02:53.732 18331-18331/com.eldareini.kotlin.meet4match 
    E/tlin.meet4matc: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f0d0044.
    2019-06-06 19:02:53.732 18331-18331/com.eldareini.kotlin.meet4match 
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    2019-06-06 19:02:53.736 18331-18331/com.eldareini.kotlin.meet4match E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.eldareini.kotlin.meet4match, PID: 18331
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.eldareini.kotlin.meet4match.signup.PersonalDetailsFragment.onCreateView(PersonalDetailsFragment.kt:57)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d0044
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:441)
        at com.eldareini.kotlin.meet4match.Constant.<clinit>(Constant.kt:69)
        at com.eldareini.kotlin.meet4match.signup.PersonalDetailsFragment.onCreateView(PersonalDetailsFragment.kt:57) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: it's throwing `Resources NotFoundException` maybe it can't find `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, you are using `getText()` somewhere with an invalid resource. Maybe you can also try to clean the project and re-sync gradle.

Comment: I'll try to clean and rebild, but it can find the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 because when i try to put the list inside the frgment class, it work perfectly

Comment: And clean and re-sync the project did't help

Comment: @Eldar do you have any other code in your `Constant` class? Any call to `getString(xxx)`?

Comment: Yes, i do. I have constats with strigs from resurce

Comment: @user2340612 Thank you, you where right. that was the problem, i gave 'context' to the 'getString' metode add all is working